# Memory problems in R

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection

Here is a phenomenon that happens all to often. I try to manipulate some sort of big data, for example

```
a <- matrix( rnorm( 1e4 * 200 ), ncol= 1e4 )
gr <- factor( rep( 1:2, each= 100 ) )
l <- lm( a ~ gr )
covs <- estVar( l )
cors <- cov2cor( covs )
```

Quite often, the following error is reported:
    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 509.5 Mb

Fine. I remove some variables I don't need any more and call the garbage collector:

```
rm( a, l )
gc( TRUE )
```

However, the error persists. Now I save R and start it again. And -- a miracle happens: the memory is now available. Why? If there was not enough memory for R to allocate before, but there is enough now, what changed? Can I force R somehow to clean up without saving the data to disk and waiting until it loads them again? I don't get it.

my `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C              LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8    LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  utils     datasets  grDevices stats     methods   base
```

**P.S.:** The system appears to have plenty of unused memory left, as reported by `free`. `top` reports that my R process (before the error) is using up ~ 2GB out of my 8, and there is still plenty more left.

Comment: Did you look at any of the existing posts here on R and memory management?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Yep. Several mention using gc(), some are using (now obsolete) command line switches, also data.table() is recommended (but merging of large data is not the problem here). Most are proposing ad hoc modifications for the problem at hand such that less memory is used. I have not found an answer to my specific questions (why gc() doesn't work, why do I have to restart R).

Comment: gc() clears stuff you don't need, but if you have lots of objects in your environment using memory then it is possible you can't get a block of contiguous memory big enough. Run a session to recreate your problem again, then use `rm( list = ls() ) ; gc()` and run the code again and see if it works.

Comment: I have found that calling `gc()` a few times in a row helps as well--just wrap a `(for i in 1:n)` around it.  But in essence: "get more RAM" or "use smaller objects" is where it is at.

Comment: "Big data" and "32-bit" are generally incompatible.  RAM is super cheap these days....

Comment: Good point by Ari. Why are you using 32bit R? That can only address a max of something like 3GB memory.

Comment: First, maybe I'm confusing something, but given that I'm using a PAE kernel, I don't think addressing is a problem. My objects fall well below that mark anyway. Second, I have 8GB on my workstation and 12GB on my laptop; both experience the same problem. Finally, yes, getting more memory might be a practical remedy, but I'd like to understand where the problem comes from. @SimonO101: the session already is clean apart of the objects mentioned in my post.

Comment: @January kernel... whatever... As I understand it, 32bit R is only capable of addressing 32bit memory addresses = ~3GB. You could have 8000TB RAM for all the good it would do you using 32bit R, you can still only use 3GB. Just use 64bit R!!!!

Comment: 64-bit R requires a 64-bit OS, or in other words, a complete reinstall.  But yes, your point is generally valid: on systems with more than 4gb, there is no point running a 32-bit OS.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: well, I am deeply prejudiced against the 64b system. Last time that I tried them, around the time the dinosaurs were still walking on Earth, I got in such a library and dependency hell that I still shudder at the thought of switching to 64b. But maybe I should finally force myself to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and use 64-bit R to take advantage of more RAM. From `?Memory-limits`:

> ***Unix***
>   The address-space limit is system-specific: 32-bit OSes imposes a limit of no more than 4Gb: it is often 3Gb. Running 32-bit executables on a 64-bit OS will have similar limits: 64-bit executables will have an essentially infinite system-specific limit (e.g. 128Tb for Linux on x86_64 cpus).

Comment: This is weird. Address-space depends on the kernel, kernel uses the PAE extension and is able to address the full memory.

Comment: It appears he is using a 32 bit machine, so this wouldn't be possible. Note `Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)` from `sessionInfo`

Comment: @gwatson so why have 8GB ram on a 32bit OS? I assume there is a dual-boot or he is using some kind of virtualbox setup?

Comment: @January: AFAIK you get access to all your memory with PAE but the single largest chunk is still 3 gb.  You can't make a 32-bit int any larger via a kernel extension.

Comment: @gwatson: nah, I'm just old and still treat 64b systems as a novelty. This is the first time I see a reason to move from 32b.

Comment: @gwatson ah, I've just googled `PAE`. Ok. SO the new answer would be- instal a 64bit OS then use 64bit R.

Comment: @SimonO101: frankly, I don't believe that this is my solution, but I will try it nonetheless. And I don't believe that it is my solution because if it really was the problem with allocating a large vector then restarting the session would not help. Right now my session takes 1.6Gb and can't allocate a vector of 0.5 Gb. I restarted it -- and it worked. This. Is. Not. Normal.

Comment: @January if you could control exactly where in the address space objects were allocated you could probably avoid this problem, but you can't. A tiny object allocated into the middle of the address space will cut the maximum size of a single chunk of allocable memory in half. Therefore to reliably avoid this problem you need a bigger address space where the probability of getting a contiguous block of memory big enough for the problem at hand is essentially 1.

Comment: @SimonO101: ok, that might be an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: OK, it did help. However, now I'm stuck with a semi-stable Ubuntu with compiz crashing on a daily basis... but then, that is a separate problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else can be done on a 32 bit machine. Maybe trying using one of the popular out of memory processing packages like `bigmemory`? Here's a link, http://www.bigmemory.org/